# I have a NEXUS 4 device, I am not able to unlock because some digits are not responding. Is there a way to remotely change password?

Tags: locked-out

I have a NEXUS 4 device, I am not able to unlock because some digits are not responding because of touch screen issue. Is there a way to remotely change password?

I can pick a new password where the digits I press will respond.

I tried the google.com/android/devicemanager but it only locked, there was no unlock option.

Thanks,
Satish

Comment: I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. Please check with [its tag-wiki](/tags/locked-out/info), where we've already aggregated material on the topic. With some luck, one of those solutions fits your device as well. If not, please [edit] your question and include some more details, eg. whether USB debugging is enabled on the device (as some approaches would need that).

Answer (score 0):

More of a hack, but I bought a micro usb to usb adapter, plugged in the mouse and was able to press on the buttons

Comment: Nexus 4 doesn't have native OTG function.